# H2 database: UPDATE method

Tags: sql, h2

I've created a table with constraint (UNIQUE) in H2

```
table (Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL UNIQUE, count INT NOT NULL)
```

for some reason when I try to update existing row using UPDATE statement
I get "Unique index or primary key violation"

if the row doesn't exist it creates one without violations.
did anyone encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: please show us your SQL statement - we can't really help you otherwise!

Comment: You are updating the value to a name that already exists.

Comment: maybe you're trying to update your primary key to some value that currently is assigned to another entry